# Setting up AspComet Chat Sample on IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, comet, server-push

I have managed to deploy the chat sample on IIS7 and is already viewable however after asking for the nickname and password. I receive this messages:

`System: Handshake complete. Successful? false`

`System: Request on channel /meta/handshake failed: No message`

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="POST" path="comet.axd" validate="false" type="AspComet.CometHttpHandler, AspComet"/>
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I am running project `Chat-VS2010`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a relative path issue. [.ashx cannot find type error on IIS7 , no problems on webdev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253367/ashx-cannot-find-type-error-on-iis7-no-problems-on-webdev-server) . Will change accepted answer when someone comes up.