# .ashx cannot find type error on IIS7 , no problems on webdev server

Tags: iis-7, comet, httphandler, ashx

I am trying to make [AspNetComet.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/?2vshj9cge26g7va) work on IIS7 
(a simple comet chat implementation) Here is a portion of my web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST" path="DefaultChannel.ashx" type="Server.Channels.DefaultChannelHandler, Server"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
       <add name="DefaultChannelHandler" verb="POST" path="DefaultChannel.ashx" type="Server.Channels.DefaultChannelHandler, Server"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

When I publish the website on my localhost IIS7 I receive an error:

`POST http://localhost/DefaultChannel.ashx 500 Internal Server Error`

`Could not load type 'Server.Channels.DefaultChannelHandler`

The target framework of this project is .Net 2.0 I tried the Classic and Integrated Mode application pool for .Net 2.0 with no luck. I also tried converting the project to 4.0 and tried the Classic and Integrated Mode application pool for .Net 4.0 with no luck. I also tried adding the managed handler through IIS Manager's Handler Mappings.

If you have time please [download the source](http://www.mediafire.com/?2vshj9cge26g7va) (184kb) to reproduce the problem on your own machine. The zip contains a VS2010 solution (.Net 2.0). You could also try to convert this to .Net 4.0

I am using Windows 7 anyway if that matters. If you need more details, please drop your comments below. This is working fine by the way on my webdev server.

*NOTE:* I created a version of this question here as I believe it suits SO better (based on the tags and user base) than what I posted on SF https://serverfault.com/questions/245241/ashx-cannot-find-type-error-on-iis7-no-problems-on-webdev-server

Comment: Looks like the type is not being loaded. Have you tried giving fully qualified name in the web.config? e.g. AssemblyName, Version=n.m.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xyz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example chat code of AspNetComet from methodworx. When deploying it to your local development environment. I would assume that you don't have your own domain thus you will create a web application underneath the `Default Website`. That makes `http://localhost/DefaultChannel.ashx` and invalid path.

You then have to append the directory name of web application similar to this. `http://localhost/WebApplicationName/DefaultChannel.ashx` . On the other hand AspNetComet will encounter another error something like `comet client does not exist`.

I have resolved this by converting the service reference `.svc` to a `.asmx` web service.